# PHP String Search

Tags: php, strpos

Okay so I'm struggling more than I should with this.  I've been to the blogs and I don't see what I'm doing wrong.  I have a large string of text that is getting returned from a server.  This text is XML.  I have a contactId tag in the returned xml.  I'm using php which I'm still kinda new to.  I'm using the strpos function to try and find the location of the start and end tag in the xml.  I know that it is in there so that isn't the problem.  However when I echo out the result to the call of that function I get nothing instead of the position like I would expect.  My code is below and help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

```
$contactIdStart = strpos($result, '<contactId>');
$contactIdEnd = strpos($result, '</contactId>');
echo $contactIdStart;
echo "*";
echo $contactIdEnd;

if ($contactIdStart === false)
    echo "bah";
else
    echo "humbug";
```

Nevermind everyone.  I'm dumb.  strpos is case sensitive I guess.

Comment: Why don't you use proper XML parsers for this?

Comment: Kinda thought it was overkill for what I need.  Just need to pull a tiny bit of data out.

Comment: All you have to do is to be lazy on this one. Use an XML parser to do the job for you. Easy.

Comment: Could you post the XML? Thanks

Comment: What's in the result? Are you sure it's the text you think? Can you post your xml code?

Comment: Below is the section of the xml that gets returned from the server.  I've just encoded the numbers for privacy reasons.  Thanks.
<stEmail>fake@email.com</stEmail><ContactId>####-#####</ContactId><OpportunityId>####-####</OpportunityId>

Comment: wow as soon as I posted that I realized this is a case sensitive problem.  Thanks!

Comment: +1 to @Marcus, because string handling on long strings is painful. Are you sure that: 1) the entire source string is represented in your data, not cut off by cURL or whatever other library is getting your data; and, 2) that the strpos is getting you the right instance of the tag you're looking for?

Comment: From personal experience I know that getting the XML parsers to work in PHP can sometimes be quite a hassle (install the extension if it is not installed, try to update PHP because of a bug in libxml, find out there is no newer version of PHP in the repository you are using, try to compile PHP manually, ...). I totally understand if the OP prefer to use `strpos` in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strpos()` is case sensitive. Use `stripos()`for case insensitive search, or fix the capitalisation (`ContactId` instead of `contactId`).

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah I just realized that.